# Flutter WebView Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, webview-flutter

I am loading a web view in my flutter project. in there I am getting an error after loading the webpage.

i am using webview_flutter: ˆ2.0.13

is anyone have any solutions for this...??

this is the error,

```
I/Choreographer(1378): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some web-view specific features? Why not just use `url_launcher`?

Comment: i need to open the webpage in the flutter app itself. that's why i don't use the url_launcher